# content script can not handle message from background after chrome.tabs.executeScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

chrome : 54.0.2840.87

This is my first chrome extension and I am new to javascript.

my manifest.json :

```
"background": {
    "persistent": true,
    "scripts": ["lib/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js", "background.js"]
},
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content-scriptA.js",
           "lib/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"],
    "css": ["res/css/ms-0.0.1.css"]
}],
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://connect.facebook.net; object-src 'self'",
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "storage",
    "identity",
    "<all_urls>"
],
```

background.js :

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (message_from_A) {
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: false}, function(tabs) {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content-scriptB.js"});
    });
  }
  if (message_from_B) {
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: false}, function(tabs) {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {to : "A", do: "..."});
    });
});
```

and

```
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, response) {
      console.log("...");
  });
```

handlers for content-scriptA.js, content-scriptB.js each.

content-scriptA is for rendering A.html, content-scriptB is for rendering B.html in the same iframe while using my extension.

What I want do is when user wants to go back to A.html from B.html, render A.html with content-scriptA.js.

When I execute content-scriptB.js I thought both A.js and B.js are going, but when I sendMessage from background, none of them answered.

I tried to use port, reload same script and so on, but still can't find the way TT

Thanks for any help, and reading my question.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. Also `addListener({console.log("...");});` is not a valid syntax. `message_from_A` and `message_from_B` aren't defined. Make sure you know how to use devtools debugger (breakpoints and stuff), both for content script and the background page script. And your `chrome.tabs.query` looks for inactive tabs? Why? It just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Thacks for comment, I edited my question and yes it was the problem due to the "active".... thaks for help..!!

Comment: In addition to the issues wOxxOm mentions (e.g. you don't show how `message_from_A` and `message_from_B` are defined): You have asked us to debug communication between your scripts, but you have not shown us the code for *content-scriptA.js* or *content-scriptB.js*, which makes it impossible to do anything other than **guess**. Note: in your *manifest.json* you, very likely, want to load jQuery before *content-scriptA.js*.

Comment: Please provide a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem.

Comment: Thanks for you all! I did not aware of that... shame on me lol